# How can I use a downloaded ubuntu image to install?

Tags: system-installation, usb

I am planning to install an Ubuntu system in my laptop computer. 
After downloaded an Ubuntu image file, how can I use it with USB stick? Do I have to make the USB bootable? If it is so, how can I make it?

Comment: you can use 1 of this 2 easy program on windows to transform your USB stick into USB bootable of Ubuntu : Rufus and Unetbootin. But before using one of these program, save data of your USB stick into your internal HDD because your USB stick will be **formatted** and all data inside will be **removed**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to create a bootable image on a flash drive.
Rufus is a pretty east tool to do it for Windows. Find it [here](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

Detailed steps is given in Ubuntu website: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#2

Answer (score 1):

For Windows I prefer UNetbootin, there are versions for Windows, Linux and Mac. The latest version works with BIOS and UEFI.

https://unetbootin.github.io/